# Triggering WP7 app from SMS content

Tags: windows-phone-7

I got request from client today to have our Windows Phone 7 app activate, if SMS message contains some sort of link or command. I've been looking around for any kind of hints if it is double, but have found none so far.

Anyone knows the way to do it?

So again, you receive SMS with a link - you click on link and application starts.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not possible with Windows Phone 7.

No workaround.
There is no way for your app to start except via the user: tapping it in the app list; tapping a live tile; tapping a toast message sent for your app; or tapping a notification raised by your app.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could do would be to send a toast notification via the push notification service; whilst not specifically an SMS, you can at least launch your app from it *if the user taps on the notification*.